# PostgreSQL function to select max values of split record

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, plpgsql

I have a number of tables 'App_build', 'Server_build' with a column called 'buildid' and it contains a large number of records. I.e.:

```
buildid
-----------
Application1_BLD_01
Application1_BLD_02
Application1_BLD_03
Application2_BLD_01
Application3_BLD_01
Application3_BLD_02
Application4_1_0_0_1 - old format to be disregarded
Application4_1_0_0_2
Application4_BLD_03
```

I want to write a function called `getmax(tablename)` i.e. `getmax('App_build')`
which will return a recordset which lists the highest values only. I.e:

```
buildid
--------
Application1_BLD_03
Application2_BLD_01
Application3_BLD_02
Application4_BLD_03
```

I am new to SQL so am not sure how to start - I guess I can use a split command and then the `MAX` function but I have no idea where to start.

Any help will be great.

Comment: If "old format" is to be disregarded, how is it defined *exactly*? Also, how is the application name "Application1" defined? Version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the help. The version of PostgreSQL is 9.2.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the help the answer provided works fine mostly.
The version of PostgreSQL is 9.2.
It turns out I made a mistake in the thinking the old format was to be disregarded.
Format of buildid varies depending on the table.
Table App_build format is [Application Name]_BLD_[Major Vesrion]_[Minor Version]_[Bugfix]_[BuildNumber]_[Optional PatchNumber] for example MyApp_BLD_1_0_0_1 is the first release and another example with the optional patch number would be MyApp_BLD_2_1_1_25_P01. I need to find the highest release number.
The Server_build table is as described above. @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: Not sure, what the question is now. In any case, please *edit* essential additional info into the question with proper format.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming current version PostgreSQL 9.2 for lack of information.

#### Plain SQL

The simple query could look like this:

```
SELECT max(buildid)
FROM   app_build
WHERE  buildid !~ '\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+$'  -- to exclude old format
GROUP  BY substring(buildid, '^[^_]+')
ORDER  BY substring(buildid, '^[^_]+');
```

- The `WHERE` condition used a regular expression:

  ```
  buildid !~ '\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+$'
  ```

  Excludes `buildid` that end in 4 integer numbers divided by `_`.

  `\d` .. character class shorthand for digits. Only one backslash `\` in modern PostgreSQL with  [`standard_conforming_strings = ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS).
  `+`  .. 1 or more of preceding atom. 
  `$`  .. As last character: anchored to the end of the string.

  There may be a cheaper / more accurate way, you did not properly specify the format.
- `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` extract the the string before the first occurrence of `_` with [`substring()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) as app name to group and order by. The regexp explained:

  `^` .. As first character: anchor search expression to start of string.
  `[^_]` .. Character class: any chracter that is *not* `_`.

  Does the same as `split_part(buildid, '_', 1)`. But [`split_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) may be faster ..

#### Function

If you want to write a function where the table name is variable, you need **dynamic SQL**. That is a plpgsql function with [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getmax(_tbl regclass) 
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
EXECUTE format($$
   SELECT max(buildid)
   FROM   %s
   WHERE  buildid !~ '\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+$'
   GROUP  BY substring(buildid, '^[^_]+')
   ORDER  BY substring(buildid, '^[^_]+')$$, _tbl);

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM getmax('app_build');
```

Or if you are, in fact, using *mixed case identifiers*:

```
SELECT * FROM getmax('"App_build"');
```

[**->SQLfiddle demo.**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html)

More info on [the object identifier class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) **`regclass`** in this related questions:
[Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a groupwise_max. It can be done with `MAX()` but the usual way is left join:

```
SELECT b1.buildid
FROM builds AS b1
LEFT JOIN builds AS b2 ON 
split_part(b1.buildid, '_', 1)=split_part(b2.buildid, '_', 1)
AND
split_part(b1.buildid, '_', 3)::int<split_part(b2.buildid, '_', 3)::int
WHERE b2.buildid IS NULL;
```

But since you're using PG it can be done with `DISTINCT ON ()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (split_part(buildid, '_', 1)) buildid
FROM builds 
ORDER BY split_part(buildid, '_', 1),split_part(buildid, '_', 3)::int DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/308bf/9